# Possible question of interest on Seasoned Advice

Tags: discussion

[Why is the tin lining bubbling on copper pan?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/122743/why-is-the-tin-lining-bubbling-on-copper-pan) was posted on Seasoned Advice. Any A&C readers with metalworking background or experience tinning copper kitchenware may want to offer answers there.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is intended to draw attention to a single question on a sister site, which is not what Meta is for.